# checking for all special character in a text box?

Tags: javascript

Any one having the java script function for checking whether a text box contain only special characters so return false  .

Comment: You can use regex for these, whatever the special character are.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to allow all other charecters except special charecters

```
 function inputAlphaNumericAndSpaceOnly(e) {
  var key = keyFromEvent(e);
  var re = /^[ A-Za-z0-9]$/;
  return re.test(String.fromCharCode(key)) || commonControlKey(key);
}//and
function keyFromEvent(e) {
  if (window.event)
     key = window.event.keyCode;
  else if (e)
     key = e.which;
  return key;
}
```